# Why there is layout misorder in last button in this android app?

Tags: android, android-layout

[image: last button image out of order]

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Admissions"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:textColor="#33b5e5"         
        android:textSize="28dp" 
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.75" >


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-7dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-6dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-6dp"
        android:gravity="fill"
        android:text="Application Form"
        android:shadowColor="#ffffff"
        android:shadowDx="2"
        android:shadowDy="2"
        android:shadowRadius="1"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ab" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-7dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-6dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-6dp"
        android:gravity="fill"
        android:text="Prospectus"
        android:shadowColor="#ffffff"
        android:shadowDx="2"
        android:shadowDy="2"
        android:shadowRadius="1"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ab" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-7dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-6dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-6dp"
        android:gravity="fill"
        android:text="Scholarship"
        android:shadowColor="#ffffff"
        android:shadowDx="2"
        android:shadowDy="2"
        android:shadowRadius="1"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ab" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-7dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-6dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-6dp"
        android:gravity="fill"
        android:text="Counselling"
        android:shadowColor="#ffffff"
        android:shadowDx="2"
        android:shadowDy="2"
        android:shadowRadius="1"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ab" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-7dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-6dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-6dp"
        android:gravity="fill"
        android:text="Admission Helpline"
        android:shadowColor="#ffffff"
        android:shadowDx="2"
        android:shadowDy="2"
        android:shadowRadius="1"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ab" />

</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

i have made a app in which i applied image to the end of button, a arrow button. this i hav done by using drawableright. but at last button, i button comes some what out of order.. why is that?
i have tried to reduce the text "admission helpline" to just "admission" so as to see if there is problem of some text formatting problem, but that don't work too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For other buttons except the last one you have used:

```
 android:layout_alignLeft
```

But for the last one you are using:

```
android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button4"
```

Change **alignRight** to **alignLeft** as:

```
  android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button4"
```

Here is the outcome:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Change alignRight of last Button to alignLeft.